# Why Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls over System.Web.UI.WebControls?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am building visual web parts for SharePoint 2010 Foundation, using ASP.NET 3.5 in Visual Studio 2010.  For those who are new, these are like making a custom "normal" .net control that you can drop onto a SharePoint page (because SharePoint is built on .net anyway).

As I'm looking at various examples online to make an input form, I notice some SharePoint specific versions of web controls.  Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls generally inherit from System.Web.UI.WebControls so would generally include or implement their functionality.

What I have yet to see is a nice listing or description of the benefits of the various SharePoint specific versions of these controls.  Why go to the effort of using these specialized versions?

One example I do know is the SharePoint GridView.  I found that when used with a DataSource, it has the paging and sorting built-in.  So that's nice.

Does anyone know of a listing of similar "benefits" to many of the other controls?  I have yet to find a nice one.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should use the SharePoint controls vs. .NET since a) they include some additional features (as you know the GridView already but more importantly, b) they are 'SharePoint Aware', thus security trimming and such things are taken care of. After all, these are the same controls used by the SharePoint UI so best to stay in line.

In all cases the SharePoint controls are hybrids of the System.Web.UI namespace. The only way you would concern yourself with using the 'raw' .NET controls would be for compatibility outside of SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks David.  I think that you must be right - there must be some handy things built-in to the SP controls that make them appealing over the basic .net ones.  I was just looking for a site or listing that helps explains those appealing points to me so I can a) explain my choices, and b) take advantage of them in my development.

I'll look into your comment about security trimming - that's the type of thing I was curious for.  What added details they offer.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome - in general, when in the context of a SharePoint site, it is better to use what SharePoint does. Of course, it always depends on exactly what you are doing.